# JS Function not working on external document

Tags: javascript

I have this function:

```
var titleLetters = new Array();
    var titleLettersShadow = new Array();

titleLetters[0] = $('.title_main:nth-of-type(1)'); titleLettersShadow[0] = $('.title_shadow:nth-of-type(1)');
titleLetters[1] = $('.title_main:nth-of-type(2)'); titleLettersShadow[1] = $('.title_shadow:nth-of-type(2)');
titleLetters[2] = $('.title_main:nth-of-type(3)'); titleLettersShadow[2] = $('.title_shadow:nth-of-type(3)');
titleLetters[3] = $('.title_main:nth-of-type(4)'); titleLettersShadow[3] = $('.title_shadow:nth-of-type(4)');
titleLetters[4] = $('.title_main:nth-of-type(5)'); titleLettersShadow[4] = $('.title_shadow:nth-of-type(5)');
titleLetters[5] = $('.title_main:nth-of-type(7)'); titleLettersShadow[5] = $('.title_shadow:nth-of-type(7)');
titleLetters[6] = $('.title_main:nth-of-type(8)'); titleLettersShadow[6] = $('.title_shadow:nth-of-type(8)');
titleLetters[7] = $('.title_main:nth-of-type(9)'); titleLettersShadow[7] = $('.title_shadow:nth-of-type(9)');
titleLetters[8] = $('.title_main:nth-of-type(10)'); titleLettersShadow[8] = $('.title_shadow:nth-of-type(10)');
titleLetters[9] = $('.title_main:nth-of-type(11)'); titleLettersShadow[9] = $('.title_shadow:nth-of-type(11)');
titleLetters[10] = $('.title_main:nth-of-type(12)'); titleLettersShadow[10] = $('.title_shadow:nth-of-type(12)');
titleLetters[11] = $('.title_main:nth-of-type(13)'); titleLettersShadow[11] = $('.title_shadow:nth-of-type(13)');
titleLetters[12] = $('.title_main:nth-of-type(14)'); titleLettersShadow[12] = $('.title_shadow:nth-of-type(14)');
titleLetters[13] = $('.title_main:nth-of-type(15)'); titleLettersShadow[13] = $('.title_shadow:nth-of-type(15)');
titleLetters[14] = $('.title_main:nth-of-type(16)'); titleLettersShadow[14] = $('.title_shadow:nth-of-type(16)');

function blinkLetter(){

    var ott = new Array (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14);
    var returnNumber = ott[Math.floor(Math.random()*ott.length)];

    var finalLetter1 = titleLetters[returnNumber];
    var finalLetter2 = titleLettersShadow[returnNumber];

    finalLetter1.css('opacity','.6');
    finalLetter2.css('opacity','.6');

    setTimeout(function(){
        finalLetter1.css('opacity','.9');
        finalLetter1.css('opacity','.9');
    },Math.floor(Math.random() * (500- 200 + 1)) + 200);

    setTimeout(function(){
        finalLetter1.css('opacity','.6');
        finalLetter2.css('opacity','.6');
    },Math.floor(Math.random() * (850- 550 + 1)) + 550);

    setTimeout(function(){
        finalLetter1.css('opacity','1');
        finalLetter2.css('opacity','.4');

        var ot2 = new Array (0,1);

        if (ot2==0){
            setTimeout(function(){
                finalLetter1.css('opacity','.1');
                finalLetter2.css('opacity','.1');
            },Math.floor(Math.random() * (500- 200 + 1)) + 200);

            setTimeout(function(){
                finalLetter1.css('opacity','1');
                finalLetter1.css('opacity','.4');
            },Math.floor(Math.random() * (900- 500 + 1)) + 500);
        }
    },Math.floor(Math.random() * (1400- 1270 + 1)) + 1270);

    var randomTimeGen = Math.floor(Math.random() * (2500 - 200 + 1)) + 200;
    setTimeout(blinkLetter,randomTimeGen);
}
```

As of it's length, I decided to put it in an external JS file but that way it doesn't work.

I tried the following:

- wrap it in `$(function(){});`
- wrap it in `$(document).ready(function(){});`

But that didn't worked. Any ideas?

Comment: What errors are you getting? What code did you use to include the file?

Comment: I'm not getting any erros, I also have another function in the file but that works. I tried putting this one below and above of the other one but it didn't work either.

Comment: Could you send us link, if you testing online?

Comment: I have fixed it, it was executing the function before loading the DOM so I used a load() function to actually execute the code in the main document!